# query to auto-increment id in parent table after insert new row in child table

Tags: mysql, laravel

Is there any way to autoincrement id in table, which I'm inserting values in another table associated with the first table, 
which the first table including only id value, and the second table including id ,product name, language, .... product_id ( FK ) for the first table.

How can I do that in a query in laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always insert into first table first and use `last_inserted_id` to insert records into second table, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO first_table (value) VALUES ('value'); 
INSERT INTO second_table (id,other_value) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'test');
```

Assuming you already have an `auto increment` sequence defined, it will always give you latest id which can be used to insert records into second table.

**Update**

For muliple inerts, you can `set` the id into a variable and use it for multiple inserts e.g.:

```
SET @last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO second_table (id,other_value) VALUES (@last_id, 'test');
INSERT INTO second_table (id,other_value) VALUES (@last_id, 'test');
```

Comment: Thank you , I can understand now how can i do that , but can you tell me how to insert double rows at the second table using only one query .